# Scala scopt: argument required() based on one or more other arguments

Tags: scala, scopt

I am used to use Scala `scopt` for command line option parsing. You can choose whether an argument is `.required()` by calling the just shown function.

How can I define an argument that is required only if another argument has been defined?
For instance, I have a flag `--writeToSnowflake` defined via scopt like this:

```
opt[Unit]("writeToSnowflake")
    .action((_, config) => config.copy(writeToSnowflake = true))
```

If I choose that a job writes to snowflake, a set of other arguments become mandatory. For instance, `--snowflake_table`, `--snowflake_database`, etc.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: [cmd](https://github.com/scopt/scopt#commands)?

Comment: Hi @Dima, could you expand a bit more? I have managed to write some arguments nested to another one using the `.children()` property. Now, how I am gonna pass them to my application? Using the regular `--whatever` even for the children? Also,  am I able to use `children()` without `cmd()`?

Comment: I don't know really, I am just reading the doc. The examples seem to be fairly clear (like `foo command1 child1 child2 command2 child3 child4`, but I suggest, if something is unclear, you just experiment with it and see for yourself what it does. Same goes for `children` without `cmd`: I don't _think_ you can do it, but if you try it and it works, that would prove me wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that `.children()` can be used outside of `.cmd()`s to achieve what I asked. This is an example:

If the parent is specified, in this case if *--snowflake* is "passed" hence evaluates to `True`, then the children that are `.required()` will throw an error if they are `null` (but only when the parent is specified, like in my case).

```
opt[Unit]("snowflake")
        .action((_, config) => config.copy(writeToSnowflake = true))
        .text("optional flag for writing to Snowflake")
        .children(
          opt[Unit]("snowflake_incremental_writing")
            .action((_, config) => config.copy(snowflakeIncrementalWriting = true))
            .text("optional flag for enabling incremental writing"),
          opt[Map[String, String]]("snowflake_options")
            .required()
            .action((snowflakeOptions, config) => config.copy(snowflakeOptions = snowflakeOptions))
            .text("options for writing to snowflake: user, privateKey, warehouse, database, schema, and table")
        )
```